# React Native Do not use setState in componentDidMount (react/no-did-mount-set-state)

Tags: javascript, react-native

playing with react native and API I've faced this kind of issue:
Do not use setState in componentDidMount (react/no-did-mount-set-state)
Who knows the reason behind?

Here my piece of code
Home.js

```js
  state = {
    users: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const users = await ajax.fetchUsers();
    this.setState({users});
  }
```

Here FetchData.js

```js
async fetchUsers() {
        try {
                let response = await fetch(URI + '/users');
                let responseJsonData = await response.json();
                return responseJsonData;
            }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're getting that error because the tool in question doesn't realize you've added `async` to `componentDidMount`, so it thinks you're *synchronously* setting state in `componentDidMount`.

You shouldn't do that. `componentDidMount` is not defined as an `async` method in `React.Component`. Don't make methods `async` when they aren't defined that way by the class you're extending. Nothing handles the promise that you'd be returning if you made `componentDidMount` `async`.

Instead, use a wrapper `async` function (and handle errors!!):

```
componentDidMount() {
    (async() => {
        try {
            const users = await ajax.fetchUsers();
            this.setState({users});
        } catch (e) {
            // ...handle/report error here...
        }
    })();
}
```

Or even break it out as its own method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadInitialUsers(); // Note: No `await`
}

async loadInitialUsers() {
    // Important: This must not throw any errors, because nothing handles
    // the promise rejection that would create
    try {
        const users = await ajax.fetchUsers();
        this.setState({users});
    } catch (e) {
        // ...handle/report error here...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Spiderweb - Great!